# Django admin view limiting the selection of items from foreign key according to user

Tags: python, django, admin

I am writing code in Django for Engineering College:

1) College has Engineering Branches like Computer Engg, Mech Engg, Chemical Engg.

2) Now each Branch will have different classes like for Frst year enginnering in computer has  to classes say, FYCO1 and FYCO2

3) I have created different users for each head of the department(HOD) and following models:

```
class M_Branch(models.Model):
Branch_ID = models.CharField(max_length=20)   
Branch_Name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
def __str__(self):
    return self.Branch_Name

class M_Academic_year(models.Model):
Academic_year = models.CharField(max_length=20)
def __str__(self):
    return self.Academic_year


class M_Class(models.Model):
Branch_ID = models.ForeignKey(M_Branch)
Academic_Year = models.ForeignKey(M_Academic_year)
Class_ID = models.CharField(max_length=20)
Class_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
def __str__(self):
    return self.Class_Name
```

4) Now each HOD (user) must be able to add a class for only his own department(branch),HOW TO ACHIEVE THIS FUNCTIONALITY???

Note: I have not written any views,(and don't want to do so). I am using Django's default admin
view

Comment: you want to achieve this in the views or in the models?

Comment: I  am using django admin to add classes.....when i am logged in as HOD of Computer Engg. Foreign key ,branch,must show only one option of Computer Engg, rather than all branches...because HOD Comp Engg is concerned of his own department rather than all department...GOT IT??

Answer (score 0):

To read only branch of HOD in M_ClassAdmin first make a relation between HOD and Branch For this, make changes In Model.py as

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Add Hod Field as

```
 HOD = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

to store HOD and Branch relation

Now Model.py willbe...

```
class M_Branch(models.Model):
    HOD = models.ForeignKey(User)
    Branch_ID = models.CharField(max_length=20)   
    Branch_Name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
         return self.Branch_Name

class M_Academic_year(models.Model):
      Academic_year = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      def __str__(self):
            return self.Academic_year

class M_Class(models.Model):
     Branch_ID = models.ForeignKey(M_Branch)
     Academic_Year = models.ForeignKey(M_Academic_year)
     Class_ID = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     Class_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     def __str__(self):
           return self.Class_Name
```

Then in admin.py Override get_queryset and formfield_for_foreignkey

```
class M_ClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
       print("Query SET")
       qs = super(M_ClassAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
       if request.user.is_superuser:
           return qs
       user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
       branch = M_Branch.objects.get(HOD = user)
       print("Branch_ID_id",branch)
       return qs.filter(Branch_ID_id=branch)
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    print("I am in func::")
    if db_field.name == "Branch_ID":
        print("db_field.name",db_field.name)
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)

        if not user.is_superuser:
            print('user=',user)
            branch = M_Branch.objects.get(HOD = user)
            print('branch = ',branch)
            '''if user=='E0711001':
                kwargs["queryset"] = M_Branch.objects.filter(Branch_ID='B101')
            #elif user=='E0711002':
            else:
                kwargs["queryset"] = M_Branch.objects.filter(Branch_ID='B102')'''
            #kwargs["queryset"] = M_Branch.objects.filter(Branch_ID=user.branch.id)
            kwargs["queryset"] = M_Branch.objects.filter(Branch_Name=branch)

    return super(M_ClassAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)


fields = ['Branch_ID','Academic_Year','Class_Name']
list_filter = ['Academic_Year','Class_Name']
search_fields = ['Branch_ID','Academic_Year','Class_Name']
list_display = ('Class_Name','Branch_ID','Academic_Year')
admin.site.register(M_Class,M_ClassAdmin)
```